# Prove that $ A\subset \ell_1 $ is compact iff $A$ satisfies the following property

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, lp-spaces

> $A$ is compact iff $ A $ is bounded and, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $ n_0$ such that $ \sum_ {k=n}^\infty |x_k|\le\epsilon $ for all $n \geq n_0 $ and for all $ x\in A  $.

To prove sufficient condition for compactness, I try to prove $A$ is totally bounded  and closed. I am able to prove only the totally bounded condition. Now how do I prove $ A $ is closed?

Answer (score 2):

Under these hypotheses, $A$ need not be closed (nor compact).  Let $x$ be the sequence $(1,0,0,\dots)$ (i.e. $x_1 = 1$ and $x_k = 0$ for $k \ge 2$).  Let $A= \{ cx : 0 < c < 1\}$.  $A$ is bounded and satisfies your uniform integrability condition (with $n_0 = 2$), but it is not closed since it has 0 as a limit point but does not contain it.

However, you should be able to show that under these conditions, the *closure* of $A$ is compact, or in other words $A$ is precompact (or relatively compact).